# The correct way of setting cookie values in Struts2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I took the following code example from a Struts2 textbook, the purpose of the code is to set a cookie in the Action class, then the jsp page is supposed to take out the content from the cookie and then display.

LoginAction class:

```
 public class LoginAction implements Action,ServletResponseAware{
    private HttpServletResponse response;
        ...
   public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response)
   {
      this.response=response;
   }

   public String execute() throws Exception
   { 
      Cookie c= new Cookie("user",getUsername());
      c.setMaxAge(60*60);

      response.addCookie(c);
      return SUCCESS;
   }
```

JSP page:

```
 <html>
  <head>

  <title>Cookie Success Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <br/>Welcome ${cookie.user.value}, thanks for logging in.
  </body>
 </html>
```

The issue I am having now is that the `${cookie.user.value}` will always be shown as blank, no matter what username I have supplied.

Maybe this is not a good way of setting cookie values in Struts2?

Comment: did you checked your browser configuration if cookie is enabled?

Comment: yes, and I've checked in different browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cookie` is just a `Map` behind the scenes. To access a Map interface from EL use `${cookie["user"].value}`

Answer (score 0):

In order to create cookies, the `HttpServletResponse` must work. It worked for me using the `servletConfig` interceptor and creating setter/getter methods for `HttpServletRespose`.